# HTML - Why doesn't my title show?

Tags: html

Im trying to make a small website, but when i try my HTML file, the title doesnt show up at all.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Games: <br></title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/AdventureGame.swf.swf">My Epic Game</a> 
    <a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/Main.swf"><br> My Other Epic Game</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Does someone know why the title doesn't show up? If yes, please tell me why! :)

Comment: because you have used `<br>`.

Comment: Where do you expect it to show up? The title will show up as the name of the browser window or tab, but as you included HTML code in the title it looks like you expect it to show up in the page content.

Comment: try <br/> you are opening the break tag not closing it but you dont even need the <br> that's why it is.

Comment: @Harry - HTML in the title element won't render anyway.

Comment: exactly but i thought id mention he is only using the opening br tag.

Comment: I dont think there can be any tags inside the title tag

Comment: so where is the title supposed to be? I thought it was like a title in a book; in the top of the content. (I started with this 30 minutes ago, don't know very much yet)

Comment: It is the text you sea in the tab. Like when you click new tab in chrome or any browser you will see the icon of the website and the text there. THAT is the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<title>`, the HTML tag is used to denote the title of the webpage and it usually appears in the browser window header (just like this window says `HTML - Why doesn't my...`, that's the title of this window), then also when you bookmark it, etc. But it's doesn't appear anywhere in the body (that's why it's in the `head` part of the HTML).

To set titles, as in the book titles, use heading tags: `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5` and `h6`.

---

Here is the info about the `title` element:

> The HTML  element (HTML Title Element) defines the title of the document, shown in a browser's title bar or on the page's tab. It can only contain text and any contained tags are not interpreted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

---

And here is some info about the heading elements:

> Heading elements implement six levels of document headings,  is the most important and  is the least. A heading element briefly describes the topic of the section it introduces. Heading information may be used by user agents, for example, to construct a table of contents for a document automatically.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

---

This is probably what you want to achieve:

```html
<h1>My Games: </h1>
<a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/AdventureGame.swf.swf">My Epic Game</a> 
<a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/Main.swf"><br> My Other Epic Game</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant write br between title tag if you want write title for a tag you should use p or h1 h2 h3 h4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> this tag use for title in browser bar </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>write your title here</h1>
 <a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/AdventureGame.swf.swf">My Epic Game</a> 
    <a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/Main.swf"><br> My Other Epic Game</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `title` element in the question is actually accepted by browsers and valid in HTML5. The string `<br>` is taken just as character data there, not as a tag.

Answer (score -1):

Use the tag H1 inside the body tag if you want to see the title in the page.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Games:</h1>   <br>  
    <a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/AdventureGame.swf.swf">My Epic Game</a> 
    <a href="http://erikwallstrom.16mb.com/Main.swf"><br> My Other Epic Game</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

The title tag is used to show a name for the page in the browser title.

Comment: You have incorrectly removed the `title` element (which is required).